# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') when i train my data using sklearn python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

i have problem with sklearn 
`Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')` 
when i train my data

```
svclassifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')  
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

but when I check :

```
print(np.any(np.isnan(X_train)))
print(np.where(np.any(np.isnan(y_train))))
print(np.any(np.isnan(y_train)))
print(y_train[0])
```

the result like this:

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
False
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
True
1.0
```

which 1.0 should be TRUE

please help me....

Comment: that is your label data, why it should be True? And you just print 4 element, why it show 5 results. Are you miss something?

Comment: i print print(np.where(X_train.values >= np.finfo(np.float64).max))